# Events not triggering in MonthView

Tags: excel, click, eventtrigger, vba

So, I'm kind of an amateur at VBA.
I'm doing an userform for many users to use at my company.

I need the user to pick a Date.
First, I tried with DTPicker, but that didn't work on the other computer I tried, so my collegue suggested I used a MonthView instead.

I put it in the form, dropping it from the Toolbox, and used this simple code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    MonthView1.Value = Date
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
      On Error Resume Next
      Dim cell As Object
      For Each cell In Selection.Cells
           cell.Value = DateClicked
      Next cell
      Unload Me
End Sub
```

Worked perfectly.

Then I tried to open the file in another computer and got the 'some objects are not available, blah blah' message. The calendar didn't show up even though I tried registering the OCX file and stuff, and I even could put a new MonthView calendar in the form, but the "existing" one didn't load.

Sooo, I tried adding the object with code, to try and avoid this, I used this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim PruebaCal As Object
Set PruebaCal = Controls.Add("MSComCtl2.MonthView.2", "PruebaCal")
PruebaCal.Value = Date
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub PruebaCal_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
      On Error Resume Next
      Dim cell As Object
      For Each cell In Selection.Cells
           cell.Value = DateClicked
      Next cell
      Unload Me
End Sub
```

This worked for the 'some objects are not available' problem, it loaded perfectly in both computers, but the Click event is not working and I have no idea how to fix that, maybe when adding controls with code the triggering events are different? I don't know.

Comment: The general answer is that you need to create a class and use `With Events` for controls created at runtime. This link describes how to do so: http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1051%20Add%20userform%20items%20on%20the%20fly.shtml. What I don't know is whether it can be done with an `Object`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you said. I tried reading the info in the link but I don't know how to apply that to my case.

Comment: That article is about creating events for controls added at runtime, which is what you are doing. The issue is that I don't know how to do it for a MonthView control. (I do for textboxes, checkboxes, etc.).